# Outdoor noise 55dB, how loud will it be (on average) 10-12 feet away?

Tags: acoustics, noise

If an outdoor air conditioner component that makes 55dB maximum noise at high speed operation, how far away would a neighbor have to be to not hear it?

Comment: Are you talking about a threshhold of  hearing ($0$ dB), or down in the normal noise background (usually $40-50$ dB in my neighborhood)? $55$ dB is not very loud for a daytime outdoor setting, unless you're trying to have a _pastoral_ setting. What's your purpose?

Comment: The table might help you?  http://www.siue.edu/~gengel/ece476WebStuff/SPL.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The transmission loss assuming nothing but spherical spreading of the sound wavefront is given by $$T_{L} = 20 \log_{10}\left( \frac{r}{r_{0}}\right) $$ where $r$ is the distance from the from the AC unit and $r_{0}$ is the measurement distance for the $55 \, \mathrm{dB}$ rating, which typically is $1 \, \mathrm{m}$. If you have a spec sheet on the AC unit that gives a different distance for sound pressure level (SPL) rating, use that instead.

The placement of the AC unit near surfaces will have some effect, too. A crude approximation says to add $3 \, \mathrm{dB}$ for every perpendicular surface: So, $+3 \, \mathrm{dB}$ if on the ground, $+6 \, \mathrm{dB}$ if near a wall, and $+9 \, \mathrm{dB}$ if placed in a corner. Obviously don't assume these are obstructions, but instead behind the unit along a line of sight from your neighbor's house. I'll call this correction $\mathrm{SR}$.

Then the estimate of SPL (in dB), $L_{p}$, at your neighbor's property is given by $$ L_{p} = 55 \, \mathrm{dB} - 20 \log_{10}\left( \frac{r}{r_{0}}\right) + \mathrm{SR}$$ where $r$ again is the distance from the unit. You can use the [table](http://www.siue.edu/~gengel/ece476WebStuff/SPL.pdf) linked by [Farcher above](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/241154/outdoor-noise-55db-how-loud-will-it-be-on-average-10-12-feet-away#comment527682_241154) and select an SPL level in dB as a goal. As an example I'll use a $30 \, \mathrm{dB}$ "quiet bedroom" level, assume the AC unit is resting on the ground $(\mathrm{SR} = 3 \, \mathrm{dB})$, and solve for $r$, giving $$ r = 25.1 \, r_{0}.$$ If $r_{0} = 1 \, \mathrm{m}$, then $r \approx 25 \, \mathrm{m} \approx 82 \, \mathrm{ft},$ which depending on where you live and how large your property is, may or may not be feasible. $30 \, \mathrm{dB}$ is quite a stringent goal, though, and even $40 \, \mathrm{dB}$ would be overly considerate of neighbors. I'll let you to do the math.

Two caveats: First, at night, when the air is cooler nearer to the ground, sound tends to refract back down toward the surface instead of spreading spherically. In this case, you could get higher dB levels, which is unfortunate since nighttime is when neighbors are most likely to notice or care. Second, appliance SPL ratings are usually made as an average over some time duration. Appliances that cycle on and off like AC units can be louder at some points of operation than the averaged rating suggests, so if your neighbors are very sensitive about their noise levels, you might attempt an SPL measurement yourself and use maximum values.